# Protagonist rebels with mutants to destroy a utopian culture only to find an authoritarian centralized brain controlling everything

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I have a memory from my childhood of an animated film about a utopian culture. The protagonists and the female supporting character discover that their society is managed by mutated humans. The mutants do all the labor, and this is hidden from the rest of the community. The couple who discover that the underlying society is unjust rebel along with the mutants, but find a giant brain that created the social structure that they cannot defeat. This brain puts the protagonist to sleep under the sea for two thousand years with a large black poisonous thorn. His mission, when he awakes, is to kill the brain with the thorn. Two thousand years later, the hero awakens to find the brain created a new world with an army of robots. He has to defeat them. Eventually, the brain and the hero meet. The brain is much older and shows signs of atrophy. The hero kills the brain by stabbing it with the black thorn.

It may be possible that I watched two movies that day and melded them together. I've asked my father about this, but he has no recollection. I've gone to comic shops and discussed the plot with salespeople, to no avail. I search the internet. Nothing comes up that is similar to my description of this film. Perhaps you can help. The film could not have been produced later than 1990. My guess is that the date range to be considered is from the 1970s to the 1980s.

My best guess is that the origin of this animation is European. The subject matter, as I infer, relates to the Soviet Communist occupation. The large brain represents the authoritarian Communist regime that Europeans feared in the mid to late 1900s, and the protagonist represents the liberator of the machinery it builds. There are many films from France with this subject matter and themes relating to the social commentary of a utopian culture.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I've marked this as an identification question, but it would help if you could be more specific as to the style (cartoon or anime) and if it was likely a series or a movie.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the movie you're looking for is [Gandahar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandahar_(film)).  It's a French animated movie, but I watched it in English so that may be the default.

> The peaceful people of Gandahar are suddenly attacked by an army of automata known as the Men of Metal, that march through the villages and kidnap their victims by turning them to stone. The resulting statues are collected and then transferred to their base. At the capital city of Jasper, the Council of Women orders Sylvain to investigate. On his journey, he encounters the Deformed, a race of mutant beings who were accidentally created via genetic experimentation by Gandahar's scientists. Despite their resentment, they are also threatened by the Men of Metal and offer to help Sylvain.
>
> Sylvain later saves Airelle, a Gandaharian woman. Together they discover the Men of Metal's base, where the frozen Gandaharians are taken through a large portal and are seemingly assimilated into more Men of Metal. The two stow away on a nearby boat which heads towards the middle of the ocean where they encounter Metamorphis, a giant brain. Sylvain and Airelle are captured and confronted by Metamorphis, who tells them that although the Men of Metal believe that he is their leader, he did not create them nor order their attack. He states that he does not want to see Gandahar fall, and that he needs time to figure out the connection between him and the Men of Metal. He then returns Sylvain and Airelle to Jasper where they learn that Metamorphis, like the Deformed, was also an experiment by Gandaharian scientists. Due to his rapid growth and increasingly violent behavior, he was abandoned in the ocean. Sylvain is ordered to kill Metamorphis with a special syringe. Sylvain returns to Metamorphis, who maintains his innocence but reveals that the Men of Metal come from the future via the portal Sylvain saw earlier. He then urges Sylvain to kill him in a thousand years, as the syringe would have no effect on him now. A skeptical Sylvain agrees and Metamorphis puts him into stasis.
>
> A thousand years later, Sylvain awakens just as they had agreed. He comes across the Deformed, who explain the true nature behind the Men of Metal: Due to Metamorphis's now advanced age, his cells can no longer regenerate, which drove him to create the Men of Metal and order them to go back in time to capture the Gandaharians so he could absorb their cells to continue living, killing the Gandaharians in the process. The metal comes from Metamorphis's dead cells metallizing with time. The Deformed, however, were abandoned as they were considered undesirable. Sylvain and the Deformed then agree to work together. The Deformed fight off the Men of Metal and rescue the remaining Gandaharians while Sylvain goes to face Metamorphis alone. The Deformed destroy the reservoir supplying Metamorphis with new cells, distracting him long enough to let Sylvain inject the syringe into Metamorphis which kills him. Sylvain, along with the Deformed and the Gandaharians escape through the portal back to their time.

Comment: Could you explain how it matches the details provided in the question?

Comment: The description nearly (99%) matches the movie description except it is 1k years not 2k.  I'm not going to go line-by-line of the description since there is 99% match.

Comment: It's worth at least mentioning that in the answer, then. Link-only answers are discouraged because there's the chance of the link going dead, or the information in the linked page changing, even with a normally-reliable site like Wikipedia.

Comment: @Sorcefyre Even if you simply quote major chunks of the Wikipedia plot summary, it's better than leaving the plain link.

Comment: This looks convincing.  I am going to watch it and let you know.  Thank you so much.

Comment: I found it on youtube.  I was going to add that the mutants are green.  They are.  This is the movie!!!  thank you.  I recognized it once the mutants took the stage.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the animated film "The Light Years" which I recall seeing in the early 2000s. I think it was based on an Asimov story.

I found link on YouTube:

(Edited: "Will be was" -> "The Light Years" and added link. Thanks to DavidW for helping me find correct name of English version)

It has a hero going to fight mutants, discovering a ruling brain, which he tries to poison - but he fails miserably, the brain is too strong / healthy. The hero and his poison is put to sleep for a long time. When he awakes the mutants have a prophesy "Will be was" about some time traveling hero saving them and things will be a it was. The brain however is playing a long game, concluding that it may get old and faulty in the distant future, and would need to die - so putting hero to sleep to come and kill it much later was part of the brains plan.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  I can't find any movie (animated or otherwise) by that name, but the Wikipedia page for [Gandahar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandahar_(film)) notes the translated script was revised by Asimov, and he contributed a quote for the start of the movie.  It's not clear but it may have been initially released under the title *The Light Years*.  Is it possible that is what you saw?

Comment: @DavidW: You are correct, I must have misremembered the title. I found it on YouTube and recognized it when I saw it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etp5QO6aI5Q